# Accord : « tel que » ou « telle que »

Tags: accord, conjonctions

Soit la phrase :

> Pour combler les lacunes théoriques des polycopiés concernant les
>   outils numériques **telle que** l'analyse dimensionnelle ont été
>   distribués.

L'accord du *tel que* est-il bien fait ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Tel* se rapporte ici à "outils" il doit donc s'accorder en genre et nombre avec celui-ci. Donc, la forme correcte est ici *tels*:

> les outils numériques tels que l'analyse dimensionnelle

Answer (score 3):

Comme l'a très bien dit Greg, il convient ici d'écrire « des outils numériques tels que l'analyse dimensionnelle ».

En revanche, si vous aviez utilisé « tel » à la place de « tel que », vous auriez écrit « des écrits traditionnels telle l'analyse dimensionnelle ».

La règle est en fait très simple : « tel que » s'accorde avec le nom placé avant lui ; « tel » s'accorde avec le mot placé après.

Si vous voulez plus d'exemples, vous pouvez consulter cet article : http://unmondesansfautes.blogspot.fr/2015/06/tel-que-vous-ne-lavez-jamais-vu.html

Answer (score 2):

C'est en effet "tels que". Plus d'explications dans cet [article détaillé sur l'accord avec tel](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/orthographe/tel-telle-tel-que-tel-quel/) :

> « Tel », utilisé pour comparer, s’accorde avec le terme le plus proche
>   des deux termes mis en comparaison. La locution « tel que » s’accorde
>   en général avec le nom qui la précède bien que des structures
>   complexes de phrase peuvent mettre le nom auquel elle se rapporte
>   après celle-ci.